# как сделать такой scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

начитался, что для создания кастомного скроллбара без jQuery никак, да и к тому же кастомные скроллы - зло, но тз требует, надо выполнять, а как - не знаю. посоветуйте как сделать такой бар

[image: вот такой scrollbar необходимо сделать по тз.]

Comment: А в чем заключается его "кастомность"?

Comment: https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin   вот этот на все вкусы - пользовался им несколько раз

Comment: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {

  background: grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: blue; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b30000; 
}
```

Comment: 1) не срабатывает в firefox
2) нужно сдвинуть скролл влево, по факту - это главная проблема. но кроссбраузерность тоже важный элемент